# Delphi Indy IdMappedPortTCP

Tags: delphi

Im using Delphi XE 5/6, default Indy version, Windows 7. IdMappedPortTCP (component put on Form) redirect local stream from FFmpeg to Twitch.tv and always near 2 hours of streaming i have IdMappedPortTCP1ExceptionSocket Error # 10053
Software caused connection abort. Tried TCPRelay and no problems so i guess something must be wrong in my app. Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

10053 is a network error.  Most likely a firewall or router is cutting the connection after it is idle for too long. I would try using Indy's TIdEventStream class as explained in the answer to this post:

[How to avoid getting an error 10053 (WSAECONNABORTED) if a HttpGet operation in Android is lasting too long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18601630/how-to-avoid-getting-an-error-10053-wsaeconnaborted-if-a-httpget-operation-in)

Comment: this problem was reproduced on few computers. Diffrence is only time. On my computer is near 110 minutes, on other 130 minutes. Thanks for info.

Comment: Yes, different computers will timeout the connection at different times depending on what's actually timing out the connection (antivirus, firewall, router, etc.)  Your app is using the connection but something on (or connected to) your computer sees it as idle.  If the connections appears idle to your computer, it will most likely look idle to the other computers as well.

Comment: wow, it works! enabling TCP keep-alives resolved my problems. Too bad this isnt as a property for mapped port, but finally after two months trying everything, now no more problem. Once again thank You!! You are my hero.